# Sumar variables en Laravel Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Talvez lo que estoy preguntando sea algo basico pero no encontre una forma correcta de hacerlo. Tengo una columna de una tabla que quiero sumarla con una variable definida: Mi codigo es algo asi:

public function handle()

```
{   
    $numero = '10';
    $eliminados = DB::table('apidata')->where('timeLive')->get();
    $total = $eliminados + $numero;
    dd($total);
 }
```

Cual seria la mejor manera de hacerlo?

Comment: cual es el resultado que deseas tener?

Comment: Quiero como resultado un numero, el resultado de la suma de $numero con el dato de la columna "timeLive".

Comment: ¿cómo hago para saber qué valor de la columna obtener? digamos que tengo 10 valores distintos en timeLive

Answer (score 0):

- En vez de usar `get()` para obtener el resultado de la consulta, yo haría uso del método de agregación `count()`a través del *query builder* para obtener el número de coincidencias resultantes de la consulta efectuada que estaría representado por un número *x*.
- Yo verificaría tu `where()` por que a mi parecer le hace falta un segundo valor, para poder comparar igualidad o desigualdad de la columna `timelive`;  es decir debería verse algo así:

Opciones

---

```
->where('timelive', 1) //que timelive sea igual a 1
->where('timelive', '<>', 1) //que timelive sea diferente de 1
```

Código:

---

```
public function handle()

{   
    $numero = '10';
    $eliminados = DB::table('apidata')->where('timeLive', algunValor)->count(); 
    $total = $eliminados + $numero;
    dd($total);
 }
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Probe el codigo y en algunValor puse por ejemplo 80, y el resultado en vez de salir 90 salió 11.

Comment: @RonnyKid por que ese 80 en el `where` solo sirve para hacer una evaluación y con base en si se cumple o no encontrar y contar los registros, es decir si de todas tus filas (400 por ejemplo), solo 1 cumple la condición dada entonces sumará a 10 uno mas quedando 11

Comment: Entonces cual seria lo correcto para cumplir con lo requerido

Comment: @RonnyKid está buena la respuesta si lo requerido es contar las filas en la tabla 'apidata' y sumarle 10. Pero no sabemos que es lo que quieres lograr con la cláusula `where('timeLive')`, así como está en la pregunta, no tiene sentido, puedes quitarla, o agregar un valor para compararlo con el de la columna 'timeLive'. . Pero no sabemos que hay en 'timeLive' (si son fechas, numeros, booleanos...), como para poder ayudarte.